# Converting client side RDLC report from Visual studio 2008 (.Net Framework 3.5) to Visual studio 2015 (.Net Framework 4.5.2)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

I am upgrading my web application from Visual Studio 2008 (.NET framework 3.5) to Visual Studio 2015(.Net Framework 4.5.2). There are around 8-10 client side RDLC reports in the application. I convert all these into new framework .NET 4.5.2.

On the page where I put report viewer control , I set the meta tag for latest IE browser (similar to as given below)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

However, when I run the reports, I get the following error.

```
Browser not supported

Report Viewer requires a standards compliant browser. Users of Internet Explorer 8 and earlier should switch to a modern browser, or if already using a modern browser target standards mode by adding the

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >

header tag to the host page.
```

SQL SERVER 2008 R2 is installed on my machine. Please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I experience this issue too but only when deployed to production in Azure Web Sites. I have tried to enable compatibility view settings to no avail. I suspect that there may also be configuration required in web or machine config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by adding DOCTYPE html tag because we were upgrading our application from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.5.2.

Earlier we had used Reportviewer 9 and now are using ReportViewer 12.0.

Thanks